# How can I make vertices of one object follow another object's vertices transformation?

Tags: vertex-groups

I have 2 objects and need a vertex group of 1st object to follow all transformation of vertex group of 2nd object. I tried parenting vertex but it only parents origins so it's not what I need. And I don't want to it with bones.

Comment: You can press Ctrl+L and copy Object Data